# Hide specific product in Shopify with Liquid based on customer tags

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm looking to hide a specific product in Shopify from all customers except those with a certain tag on their account.

I was going to use the app [Lockdown](https://apps.shopify.com/lockdown) but it's been discontinued.

So far everything I've learned says that I use something like this:

```
{% if customer.tags contains 'Bundle' %}  
{% include 'product-to-be-shown' %}
{% endif %}
```

That second line is where I'm stuck, I think I'm on the right track but I'm not entirely sure.

Any guidance is appreciated, even if that guidance takes me an entirely route to get the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.. but no cigar...

On your product template... use this instead...

```
{% if customer.tags contains 'Bundle' %}  

   Show this product as usual. 

{% else %}

   Politely tell this customer there is nothing here for them

{% endif %}
```

That is all any lockdown or other wholesale App does anyway... absolutely nothing special...

Comment: Thanks David,
Worked perfectly.